# Memory consumption of Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, airflow

as the topic, I have a question about the performance of the Airflow operator.

I want to check how the memory consumption of my DAGs or my Operators, then is there any way to check this?

Comment: Python memory consumption is particularly difficult to inspect or optimise. Is there a reason you want this, you can observe the memory consumption of your program while it's being executed?

Comment: yes, I still don't know how to observe this. The program is executed on a docker container and the docker container is running on a VM.

Comment: If you want to monitory resource usages by `task`s (and not Airflow itself), then go for monitoring / observability solutions like Prometheus + Grafana / StatsD. Here's a good one [robinhood/airflow-prometheus-exporter](https://github.com/robinhood/airflow-prometheus-exporter)